# Get list of a directory with powershell. With Created and Modified columns

Tags: powershell-ise

I have this code:

```
Get-ChildItem  -recurse | fl name, creationtime, lastwritetime
```

And i get a result of this:

```
Name          : name.exe
CreationTime  : 18-Dec-21 13:15:16
LastWriteTime : 18-Dec-21 13:15:17

Name          : name.txt
CreationTime  : 24-Dec-21 13:15:44
LastWriteTime : 24-Dec-21 13:27:43

Name          : name.png
CreationTime  : 12-Dec-21 23:55:48
LastWriteTime : 12-Dec-21 23:55:49

Name          : name.csv
CreationTime  : 24-Dec-21 14:15:19
LastWriteTime : 24-Dec-21 14:15:19

Name          : name.csv
CreationTime  : 24-Dec-21 14:16:41
LastWriteTime : 24-Dec-21 14:31:49

Name          : name.csv
CreationTime  : 24-Dec-21 14:08:07
LastWriteTime : 24-Dec-21 14:08:07

Name          : name.csv
CreationTime  : 17-Dec-21 14:02:42
LastWriteTime : 17-Dec-21 14:02:42
```

I would like to get the list formatted from the command line into table. So i tried to use this code:

```
Get-ChildItem  -recurse | ft name, creationtime, lastwritetime
```

But i get a rubbish result instead. It's so rubbish, i cant even recreate it, and that is because of files with many caracters in name.

If i use the same code on a dir with files that have less caracters in name, i can get a decent file list, like this one:

```
Name      CreationTime       LastWriteTime     
----      ------------       -------------     
name.txt 24-Dec-21 14:57:04 24-Dec-21 14:57:04
name.txt 24-Dec-21 13:15:44 24-Dec-21 13:27:43
name.csv 24-Dec-21 14:15:19 24-Dec-21 14:15:19
name.csv 24-Dec-21 14:16:41 24-Dec-21 14:31:49
name.csv 24-Dec-21 14:08:07 24-Dec-21 14:08:07
```

My question is how can i set in command line option to shorten the name. Optionally using character filter.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a format table to setup up how you want the output displayed. Here's an example which you can use and adjust to your needs.

```
Clear-Host
$fmtGCI = @{Expression={$_.Name};
            Label="File Name";Width=50;Align="Left"},
          @{Expression={$_.CreationTime.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")};
            Label="Creation";Width=10},
          @{Expression={$_.LastWriteTime.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")};
            Label="Modified";Width=10}

Get-ChildItem -Path 'G:\BEKDocs\ACTS\Communications Committee\K4Training App' | 
     FT $fmtGCI
```

Note: setting a shorter width for the filename will just truncate it so be careful how you set it.

Of course you can add more items like the file times if you need them. You can also break the name up into Basename and Ext.

Sample output:

```
File Name                                          Creation   Modified  
---------                                          --------   --------  
Videos                                             2021-12-16 2021-12-21
Bruce Edit.png                                     2021-10-04 2021-10-04
Bruce interests.png                                2021-10-04 2021-10-04
Dining Chophouse menus.png                         2021-10-04 2021-10-04
Dining desert menu.png                             2021-10-04 2021-10-04
Directory Fitness search.png                       2021-10-04 2021-10-04
Directory Gardening search.png                     2021-10-04 2021-10-04
```

Comment: You can also break the name up into Basename and Ext. < yes please, how do i do that? Or a better question: How do i brake it to a known caracter that repeat itself on the big fil name files. Thank you.

Comment: How can i add the creation hour? I tried to ad here: ("yyyy-MM-dd") hh:mm:ss and tried with HH:mm:ss but to no avail. What i get is a standard hour of 12:00:00 or 00:00:00 an all files and what i'm interested in is to see the difference between Cration and Moddified at the level of mm and ss. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I can't accept as an answer RetiredGeek's post, but i can half accept as an answer here.

It is half (or more than 80% correct answer) because i figure it out what to change to get what i wanted/nedded.

My main scope was to get the difference between **Created** and **Modified** at the level of **mm** and **ss**.

Took his code and moddified:

```
          @{Expression={$_.CreationTime.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")};
            Label="Creation";Width=10},
```

With:

```
          @{Expression={$_.CreationTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")};
            Label="Creation";Width=20},
```

So now the code looks like this:

```
Clear-Host
$fmtGCI = @{Expression={$_.Name};
            Label="File Name";Width=50;Align="Left"},
          @{Expression={$_.CreationTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")};
            Label="Creation";Width=20},
          @{Expression={$_.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")};
            Label="Modified";Width=20}
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\+\_+_\2021\12 2021' | FT $fmtGCI
```

And what i get is this:

```
File Name                                          Creation             Modified            
---------                                          --------             --------            
Testing1 Testiy Noname1 #Serie - 'Fileyx filexx... 2021-12-31 03:19:23  2021-12-31 03:19:23
Testing2 Testiy Noname1 #Serie - 'Fileyx filexx... 2021-12-31 04:07:07  2021-12-31 04:07:07
Testing3 Testiy Noname1 #Serie - 'Fileyx filexx... 2021-12-31 06:05:33  2021-12-31 06:05:33
Testing4 Testiy Noname1 #Serie - 'Fileyx filexx... 2021-12-31 07:21:24  2021-12-31 07:21:24
Testing5 Testiy Noname1 #Serie - 'Fileyx filexx... 2021-12-31 08:35:48  2021-12-31 08:35:48
```

Thank you so so so much @RetiredGeek

And a Happy New Year :)